# PHP Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::save() in Psy Shell code on line 1

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, laravel-artisan, laravel-6, tinker

I'm new in Laravel, 
I'm using tinker to create a record:

```
$Profile=new \App\Profile();
=> App\Profile {#3038}
>>> $profile->title='Premier Titre'
PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in Psy Shell code on line 1
>>> $profile->title='Premier Titre';
=> "Premier Titre"
>>> $profile->description='Description';
=> "Description"
>>> $profile->user_id=1;
=> 1
>>> $profile->save()
PH
```

I have the following error:PHP Error:  Call to undefined method stdClass::save() in Psy Shell code on line 1

Here my profile.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
    public function user()

{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class );
}
}
```

here is my migration code:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('surname')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you define variable with capital letter:

```
$Profile=new \App\Profile();
```

and later you use it with small letter

```
$profile->title='Premier Titre'
```

So probably under the hood new stdClass object is created and obviously it doesn't have `save` method. You are also getting warning about this:

> PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in Psy Shell code on line 1

which says new object is created

So make sure you change

```
$Profile=new \App\Profile();
```

into

```
$profile=new \App\Profile();
```

to make it working