# Laravel undefined variable Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8, laravel-controller

I have had problems with my BusinessController for a long time now. It is impossible to understand what is not written so. Please help me fix mistakes; I feel I made a lot of them)

My Problem:

my database business_table.php

```php
class BusinessTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('businesses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('mail');
            $table->string('web-site');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('business');
    }
}
```

My Controller: BusinessController.php

```php
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use \App\Models\Business;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class BusinessController extends Controller
    {
    public function index()
    {
    $business = \App\Models\Business::all();
    return view('business', compact('business'));
    }
    public function createbusiness()
    {
    return view('/createbusiness');
    }
    public function store()
    {
    return view('/business');
    }
    public function create()
    {
    return view('business.create');
    }
    public  function store()
    {
    $business = new Business();
    $business->title = request()->input('title');
    $business->description = request()->input('description');
    $business->save();
    return redirect('/business');

    }
    }
```

My Model: Business.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Business extends Model
{
/**
* The table associated with the model.
*
* @var string
*/
protected $table = 'business';
}
```

My view file: business.blade.php

```php
@extends('layouts.layout')
@section('title')Бізнес@endsection
@section ('main_content')
    <h1>Бизнес</h1>
    <p>
    @foreach ($business as $singleBusiness)
        <li>{{ $singleBusiness->title}}</li>>
        @endforeach
        </p>
@endsection
```

my createbusiness.blade.php:

```php
<p>It works</p>
<form method="post" action="/business">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="title" value="" placeholder="title">
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea type="text" name="description" value="" placeholder="description"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="sumbit">Sumbit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My web.php

```php
<?php

    use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Web Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
    | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group, which
    | contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
    |
    */

    Route::get('/welcome', 'App\Http\Controllers\MainController@welcome');
    Route::get('/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\MainController@users');
    Route::get('/business', 'App\Http\Controllers\BusinessController@index');
    Route::post('/business', 'App\Http\Controllers\BusinessController@store');
    Route::get('/projects', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@index');
    Route::post('/projects', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@store');
    Route::get('/projects/create', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@create');
    Route::get('/business/create', 'App\Http\Controllers\BusinessController@createbusiness');
    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

my MainController.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function welcome()
    {
    return view('/welcome');
    }
    public function users()
    {
    return view('users');
    }
}
```

[my problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2R7Jb.png)

Comment: `Route::get('/business', 'App\Http\Controllers\MainController@business');` upload your `MainController` code as well

Comment: ok i updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add route

```
Route::get('/business', 'App\Http\Controllers\BusinessController@index');
```

you are not invoking business controller with index method, which passes:

```
return view('business', compact('business'));
```

business to business view.

### UPDATE

remove this route which results in conflict:

```
Route::get('/business', 'App\Http\Controllers\MainController@business');
```

for every path (like '/business') and verb (like get/post) only one route should exists.

### UPDATE 2

oh my gosh, you have 2 store function in your BusinessController, Remove one.

Comment: ok thanks, now my error looks like this ))))) https://imgur.com/a/QbOsTRk

Comment: i cannot load the image can you write the error message and stacktrace in your question?

Comment: Cannot redeclare App\Http\Controllers\BusinessController::store()

Comment: it said you have two identical route. are you sure you have this with Route::get and Bussiness Store With Post ??

Comment: remove other  Get '/bussiness' Route as i updated the answer

Comment: Cannot redeclare App\Http\Controllers\BusinessController::store() the same error (

Comment: have you removed the MainController '/business' ?

Comment: can you update your answer with new routes?

Comment: edit your third route to point `index` action. sorry it was my mistake

Comment: replace that with this: Route::get('/business', 'App\Http\Controllers\BusinessController@index');

Comment: ok i replace, erorr same( i updated web.php

Comment: have you cached your routs? try 'php artisan route:clear'

Comment: did but nothing changed

Comment: as my updated answer please remove one function

Comment: have you removed this from controller: `public function store()
    {
    return view('/business');
    }` ?

Comment: ok i delete Route::post('/business', 'App\Http\Controllers\BusinessController@store'); and strore function at controller. now it works

Comment: no, i mean you have 2 functions with same names in BusinessController

Comment: ok i delete only public function store()     {     return view('/business');     } yes ?

Comment: yes and you can have your store route back

Comment: ok thanks so much, I'm from Ukraine, I have other problems with English, I'm sorry if I was stupid

Comment: ouuu i forgot to ask why when I call $ business-> save (); in artisan tinker the result is an error: PHP Error: Call to undefined method stdClass :: save () in Psy Shell code on line 1

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/59583974/9287628

Answer (score 0):

as your using

`Route::get('/business','App\Http\Controllers\MainController@business');`

in your `MainController.php`

```php
public function business()
{
    $business = \App\Models\Business::all();
    return view('business', compact('business'));
}
```

here you miss to give `$business` data and loading `business.blade.php`